# Dynamically add a Component from a list of components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I will break it down to give an understanding.

I have a parent class **Item**.

I have child classes for each type of **Item** (**Weapon**, **Armor**, etc).

I have a list of all the items.

I'm trying to randomly grab an item from that list, and then add it as a component. 
My items each randomly generate their own names, stats, etc, but they are all specific to the type of item they are and so I needed them to be generated in their own classes and not just generating "Item".

So here is what I have so far.

```
public Item RandomList(List<Item> list)
    {
        return list[random.Next(list.Count)];
    }
```

This returns a random item from my list.

```
public void GenerateLoot(GameObject gameObject, List<Item> list)
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent(randomManager.RandomList(list));
    }
```

This is where I'm running into problems. It says : "cannot conver from Item to System.Type". I've tried various things such as using typeof, etc.

This is something I'm fairly new to.

Comment: gameObject.AddComponent function needs a type, not an object

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! So I'm unable to add an instance of the Type, it has to be the Type itself? Sorry Types are something I haven't had to deal with much on this level until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSL says, you need to give it a *Type* argument to *AddComponent*, as the documentation suggest:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

So my suggestion is to do it that way:

**1.First you call and add the component (similar as you do)**

```
gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Item)) as Item;
```

or my prefered way:

```
gameObject.AddComponent<Item>();
```

**2.Then add the item values and properties:**

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().value = item.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

`AddComponent` seems to not support parameters other than type of a script, and if I understood you correctly, your items are all customizable in many aspects that should be applied when you add component in runtime. I advise adding method `AddToGameobject` in class `Item`:

```
abstract class Item : Monobehaviour {
    public abstract void AddToGameObject (GameObject obj);
}

class Weapon : Item {
    int damage;
    int cooldown;
    public override void AddToGameObject (GameObject obj) {
        var copy      = obj.AddComponent <Weapon> ();
        copy.damage   = damage;
        copy.cooldown = cooldown;
    }
}

class Armor : Item {
    int protection;
    public override void AddToGameObject (GameObject obj) {
        var copy        = obj.AddComponent <Armor> ();
        copy.protection = protection;
    }
}
```

And your loot generation function will become

```
public void GenerateLoot (GameObject gameObject, List <Item> list) {
    randomManager.RandomList (list).AddToGameObject (gameObject);
}
```

If you want to attach existing component itself instead of a copy, you can't (explanations: [1](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1224399/add-an-instance-of-a-script-as-a-component.html), [2](https://answers.unity.com/questions/212402/instantiate-existing-components-and-assign-to-game.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a `GameObject Component` of type `Item`. If you try to `Add Component` Item in the `Inspector` of any `GameObject`, there is none (unless your script is called Item, but that won't do what you're trying to do).

I'm assuming in your example, you may want to generate a random item upon opening a chest. There is a couple of steps to create a fully functional item, so I can't really give it all to you, so I'll give you an idea of how you'd do it.

The following will randomly change the image of the `GameObject` by Adding Component `SpriteRenderer` and randomly change the `Sprite` value of this `Component`.

```
public class RandomSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject gameObject;
    public Sprite[] weapons; // assign an array of weapon sprites in Inspector

    void Start() {
        gameObject = new GameObject();
        SpriteRenderer gameObjectSR = // add SpriteRenderer component
            gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer)) as SpriteRenderer;

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, weapons.Length); // random index within weapons
        gameObjectSR.sprite = weapons[randomIndex]; // assign Sprite from weapons

        // instantiate object
        Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation); 
    }
}
```

So you begin with `Sprite[] weapons`, an array of weapon images (basically). In the `Start()` function, create a new `GameObject`, and add a `SpriteRenderer` (this doesn't have to be random because you want to change what the item looks like). The random part begins with obtaining a random `int` (the index which is inside the length of the weapons). Then assigning a random weapons `Sprite` onto the `GameObject`, and instantiating it. This would work as compared to your attempt because `SpriteRenderer` is a Unity `GameObject Component`.

For this `GameObject`, you may want to attach your **Weapon script** (since it's derived from the Item class) and assuming you have a Weapon function `SetDamage`, like this:

```
Weapon w = gameObject.AddComponent<Weapon>();
w.SetDamage(Random.Range(5,10)); // set weapon damage between 5 and 10
```

This will then change the value of the Weapon damage, which can be accessed by script for when you are damaging an enemy, for example.

*Note: There is probably a way to create your own components, if the normal library of components doesn't satisfy your needs.*